# Add dynamic input field that assigns new id from array

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am working on an input form for a PHP page and would like to not have to predetermine the number of input fields. Is it possible to create an 'Add Input Field' Button that adds a new input field and assigns a new id/name to the field so that it can be posted to php variable? Would this be done with an array of input field names or soemthing?

Comment: yes it is possible ,you can create input fields dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example :

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>
 <button id="button" type="button">add field!</button>
```

jquery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var id = 0;

$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    var name = 'name of '+ id;
    $('.form-group').append('<label for="'+id+'">'+name+':</label><input type="text" class="form-control"   id="'+id+'">')
    id++;
});
});
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyso9662/16/)

Comment: You're a life saver ....  so just store an array in usr? and then usr++ to increment through the array?

Comment: check edits, id is just a variable, that after we add a new input, we ll increment.

Comment: but I need a new id for the input each time one is added... sorry i may be missing something

Comment: I just started coding a few weeks ago and know very little JS

Comment: everytime you click the button you assign as id the value of variable 'id', then you increment it. so everytime you add a field you will have a unique id.
Check now the fiddle, every time you add a field you have as label '' name of x' where x is the id of the field you just added. or use your browser inspector and you will see you have unique id's